# How to set the detail height programatically in ActiveReports

Tags: activereports, componentone, grapecity

does anyone know how to set the height of the detail section in my report programatically (e.g. in detail_format or after/before_print methods)?

Setting the (float) height in detail_format for each datasource row has no effect.

Do I have to set the "Can Grow" / "Can Shrink" properties to FALSE?

Thanks in advance,
Walter

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping the CanGrow and CanShrink properties as it is (default). The detail section grow as each row renders. You can manually set the height of the detail section like this:

```
private void detail_Format(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.detail.Height = 7f;
}
```

However without any details about your requirements, I am unable to offer any other suggestions.

Comment: Hi, you wrote ".. CanGrow and CanShrink properties as it is (default)..". Default values are CanGrow = TRUE and CanShrink = FALSE, am I right?

Comment: I have set cangrow to true, canshrink to false. Additionally I have set the detail-height in detail_Format (as you suggested) plus in detail_BeforePrint and detail_AfterPrint --> No effect, the detail-height stays with height in designer....

Comment: Yes the default values are CanGrow = TRUE and CanShrink = FALSE. I think it would be better if you send in your report or a small sample to ActiveReports forums here:
http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/forum/reporting/activereports-8/

Some details about your use case would also help in determining the right approach.